# C++ Polymorphism, incomplete downcasting

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, static-cast

I have an array which holds references to a bland base type, let's call it `Object`.

I have derived `Class1` from `Object` and `Class2` from `Class1`.

```
#include <vector>

class Object {};
class Class1 : public Object {
public:
virtual std::string ToString() {return "it is 1";}
};
class Class2 : public Class1 {
public:
    virtual std::string ToString() {return "it is 2";}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Object *> myvec;
    myvec.push_back(new Class2());
    printf("%s", (static_cast<Class1*>(myvec[0]))->ToString().c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

I call `ToString()` by casting from `Object *` to `Class1 *` like so

```
    printf("%s", (static_cast<Class1*>(myvec[0]))->ToString().c_str());
```

My question is, will this output 1 or 2 when the object is in fact of `Class2` but not down cast to that specifically? Is the `virtual` keyword having the intended effect?

Comment: I'm with Falmarri; it would have taken less time to try it than to ask the question and get an answer.

Comment: Nope, it means loading up my mobile phone emulator, and I it might be useful to others. Would it have taken you less time to give a straight answer Nicol?

Comment: @John: Mobile phone emulator? C++ is C++; that's the whole point. You don't have to run it on your phone to test a basic feature of the language. All it would take is a 15 line program to test this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly misread your question when I first answered, regarding demons and your nostrils.

The `virtual` keyword will have it's intended effect.  That is, You will see 2.  Although you have casted to `Class1`, the vtable will work it's magic.

Comment: Ah yes, what an awful example my first attempt was.

Answer (score 3):

It should call `Class2`'s virtual function, since the object is of that type.

Remember: the purpose of a virtual function is to call the *actual* class's function, not the function for the class the pointer/reference currently appears to be.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a safe cast. But assuming that `myvec[i]` is a pointer the an object you are casting to, then it will call the appropriate method for that class.